# Multi-user secure shell session sharing

Tags: vim, emacs, gnu-screen, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-unity

I'm looking to do some pair programming with a collegue remotely, and I'm looking for the best tool to help us achieve this.

Ideally I'd prefer for the remote user to have as little access as possible, and it'd be preferrable if I could monitor all their actions.

GUI access is not required, shell is enough.

For example, shared tmux or screen sessions would work well, if they were easy to setup and secure.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new, non-root user account on the machine, then run tmux under that account. Screen sharing is easy and is what will "just happen" if you both "attach" to the same screen session. If there is nothing under that temporary user account that you care about, there is little damage that they could do, AFAIK, though your question may be more appropriate for https://serverfault.com/.

Comment: After giving the other user an account, a tool like [wemux](https://github.com/zolrath/wemux) might be what you are looking for.